# How can I extract Image Files from an exe?

Tags: windows, extract

I want to know how can I extract images from an exe. If you want to check out here is the [exe](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SISHdIJ3d4l9CGFj8XfkvBKrg8am_ihI/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Try Resource Hacker http://angusj.com/resourcehacker/

Comment: It could not find sadly.

Comment: the exe needs a pw, this is basically link rot.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [7-Zip](https://www.7-zip.org/) to extract an `.exe` file.

1. Install 7-Zip
2. Right click on the `.exe` file and click `7-Zip -> Extract here`
3. See if you can find the image you're looking for.